# Listen changes variable in child component

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to continuously monitor the variable - the angle in the child component. I use @ViewChild() decorator.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'angle' of undefined
```

tried various solutions, however, the problem remains

child component:

```
    export class CubeViewWebGlComponent implements OnInit {
     public angle = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0
      };
    /////Some code////////////////
    }
```

parent component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {CubeViewWebGlComponent} from './cube-view-web-gl/cube-view-web-gl.component';

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(CubeViewWebGlComponent) CubeView: CubeViewWebGlComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setInterval(this.checkCubeAngle, 1000);
  }

  checkCubeAngle() {
    console.log(this.angleCubeComponent.angle);
  }
  /////Some code////////////////
}
```

Comment: Please explain your goal and the issue you're facing. Right now, it's very burry. Consider providing a [mcve] on a sandbox such as stackblitz or codesandbox.

Comment: Sorry, console.log(this.CubeView.angle);

Comment: The task is to create a viewport to control the camera on the scene. The cube sets the view (top, side, bottom, etc.). From the component of the child - the cube is necessary to get the current angle. This angle is required to control the camera.
The angle of this one is transmitted remarkably. However, when I try to take it periodically in the browser log, an error comes out (see
above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, there will be a problem with `this` context here:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setInterval(this.checkCubeAngle, 1000);
  }
```

`this.checkCubeAngle` is a "function" function, not an arrow function, and calling it inside `setInterval` like this you're losing the component's `this`. Converting it to an arrow function

```
  checkCubeAngle = () => {
```

should help.

Comment: Yes, just change  checkCubeAngle() { console.log(this.CubeView.angle);} to checkCubeAngle = () => { console.log(this.CubeView.angle);} and its begun ideal work. Thank You very much!